# How to write java 8 healthCheck (CompositeHealthIndicator) contributor in java 17

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, java-17, health-check

I have the below code written in java 8 and now I want to rewrite same using java 17 as some of the classes are deprecated. Can you please advise how to implement below java 8 code to java 17.

```
private final CompositeHealthIndicator compositeHealthIndicator;

    @Autowired
    public ApiHealthIndicator(ObjectProvider<Map<String, HealthIndicator>> healthIndicators, OrderedHealthAggregator orderedHealthAggregator) {
        Map<String, HealthIndicator> availableHealthIndicators = healthIndicators.getIfAvailable();
        compositeHealthIndicator = new CompositeHealthIndicator(orderedHealthAggregator, availableHealthIndicators);
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        if (compositeHealthIndicator.health().getStatus().getCode().toUpperCase().equals("UP")) {
            return Health.status(healthCheckCode).build();
        }

        return Health.down().build();
    }
}
```

I tried to use `CompositeHealthContributor` in place of `CompositeHealthIndicator`, but I could not use it as its an interface. So there is no straight away replacement class for this.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 2.x, some of the health indicator classes have been changed, and `CompositeHealthIndicator` has been replaced with the `CompositeHealthContributor` interface. You can achieve the same functionality as your original code using the `HealthContributorRegistry` and `HealthEndpointGroups` classes.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class ApiHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    private final HealthContributorRegistry healthContributorRegistry;
    private final HealthEndpointGroups healthEndpointGroups;

    public ApiHealthIndicator(ObjectProvider<Map<String, HealthIndicator>> healthIndicators,
                              OrderedHealthAggregator orderedHealthAggregator,
                              HealthContributorRegistry healthContributorRegistry,
                              HealthEndpointGroups healthEndpointGroups) {
        Map<String, HealthIndicator> availableHealthIndicators = healthIndicators.getIfAvailable();
        availableHealthIndicators.forEach(healthContributorRegistry::registerContributor);
        this.healthContributorRegistry = healthContributorRegistry;
        this.healthEndpointGroups = healthEndpointGroups;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        HealthAggregator healthAggregator = healthEndpointGroups.getPrimary().getHealthAggregator();
        CompositeHealth compositeHealth = healthAggregator.aggregate(healthContributorRegistry.stream().map(HealthContributor::getHealth));

        if (compositeHealth.getStatus().equals(Status.UP)) {
            return Health.status("healthCheckCode").build();
        }

        return Health.down().build();
    }
}
```